# Может ли IComparer<type> принимать обобщенный тип type?

Tags: c#, интерфейс, compare

Ребята мы должны использовать IComparer с типом точным? (не обобщенным) Или можем использовать и обобщенный?

```
class Trees<type> : IComparer<type> 
{
 public int Compare(type X, type Y)
    {
        if (X.CompareTo(Y) != 0)   // подчеркивает CompareTo
        {
            return X.CompareTo(Y); // подчеркивает CompareTo
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: да, может принимать, тут без разницы. Все зависит от реализации его методов

Comment: окей но у меня есть проблемы с реализацией, сможете помочь? Код скину

Comment: Стоит просто отредактировать вопрос

Comment: _подчеркивает CompareTo_ - просто потому, что не знает, есть ли у переданyого type этот метод.

Comment: Ваш компарер выглядит также как стандартный [`Comparer<type>.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cfttsh47(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Так а что нужно изменить?

Comment: @Grundy как сделать это?

Answer (score 6):

Можно, но раз ваш код предъявляет какие-то требования к `type` (например, наличие у него метода `CompareTo(type)` из интерфейса `IComparable<type>`, то эти требования вы должны явно выразить в коде:

```
class Trees<type> : IComparer<type> where type: IComparable<type>
{
    public int Compare(type X, type Y)
    {
        if (X.CompareTo(Y) != 0)   // больше не подчеркивает CompareTo
        {
            return X.CompareTo(Y); // больше не подчеркивает CompareTo
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, спасибо за правку :)

Comment: Я бы ещё закешировал результат сравнения в переменную.

Comment: @VladD там можно вообще прямо напистать return, просто вопрос не о том был :)

Comment: Ну это да, но наверняка там до финального `return` были ещё проверки (я исхожу из того, что это упрощённый код). Ну да ладно.